# How can I access a css to animate in javascript Vue JS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am having a little trouble in using javascript to access a css animation. My goal in this code is if you click the next button or previous button the border should spin but I am having trouble to trigger the css animation.

This is my html

```
<template>
<div v-on:click="prev" class="prevButton"><p>&lt;</p></div>
<div class="borderTop"></div>
<div v-on:click="next" class="nextButton"><p>&gt;</p></div> 
</template>
```

This is the css

```
.border{
  position: fixed;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 120px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.555);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); 
        border-right: 120px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.226);}
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

this is the javascript

```
prev(){ 
  document.querySelector(".borderTop").animate;
}
next(){ 
  document.querySelector(".borderTop").animate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't trigger the animation from Javascript. Instead you should add your animation style to an additional class which you can add to the div for the duration of the animation.

```css
  .animate {
    animation: spin 2s linear;
  }
```

Add anther class with `animation-direction: reverse;` if you would like to reverse the animation for the prev button.

```js
prev() {
  document.querySelector('.borderTop').classList.add('animate');
    
    // Remove the animate class after the spin was performed so it works again when the button is clicked.
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector('.borderTop').classList.remove('animate');
    }, 2000)
  });
}

next() {
  document.querySelector('.borderTop').classList.add('animate');
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector('.borderTop').classList.remove('animate');
    }, 2000)
  });
}
```

Comment: I see... Thank you for the answer, thank you also for the bonus tip on reversing the animation :D

Comment: No problem, not that this is a more or less plain JS solution provided a quick solution to you already existing code. Since you're using VueJS  I would heavily suggest you to have also a look into vue transitions: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

May I ask you what happens when one of the buttons is clicked?

Comment: when the button is clicked it's purpose is to change the background image and create a spinning animation

Comment: Is the spinning animation some kind of a loading indicator? Because if yes it would be best to introduce a state whether the image is loaded or not.

Comment: nope this is just for animation purposes like a simple transition, can I ask again because if I click next or previous button rapidly it wont start the animation again

Comment: Yeah this is because the setTimeout runs for 2s since your animation takes the same time.

Comment: yes I tried to change it that the animation activates again if I clicked a button but I can't get it

Answer (score 0):

```
let borderAnimatable = document.querySelector(".borderTop")
prev(){ 
  borderAnimatable.style.animation = "spin 2s linear";
  borderAnimatable.style.WebkitAnimation = "spin 2s linear";
}

next(){ 
  borderAnimatable.style.animation = "spin 2s linear";
  borderAnimatable.style.WebkitAnimation = "spin 2s linear";
}
```